# Reverse not found Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to redirect users to another page after they click a link. I know that I need to register the redirect on urls.py and have the view on views.py

I have done all of this to my understanding, but still getting this error specifically for one redirect.

Here is my html

```
<li><a href={% url 'edit_user' %}>Edit Profile</a></li>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='app-instructor-dashboard'),
        path('logout', teachers.logout_request, name="logout"),
        path('edit_user', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
```

and views.py(teachers.py)

```
def edit_user(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
        else:
            form =UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form':form}
            return render(request, 'teachers:app-instructor-profile', args)
```

This is the error message I am getting

> NoReverseMatch at /teachers/ Reverse for 'edit_user' not found.
>   'edit_user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**UPDATE**

Based on an answer given I have made these changes
urls.py

```
...
    path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='app-instructor-dashboard'),
        path('logout', teachers.logout_request, name="logout"),
        path('edit_user/<int:pk>/', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
```

html

```
<li><a href={% url 'edit_user' request.user.pk %}>Edit Profile</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<li><a href={% url 'teachers:edit_user' request.user.pk %}>Edit Profile</a></li>
```

hope it helps